# How to inspect bindings on a Marionette view?

Tags: model-view-controller, binding, event-handling, marionette, inspect

Is there a way to examine active bindings on a [Marionette view](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/v1.1.0/docs/marionette.view.md)?
The bindings are created in the [controller](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/v1.1.0/docs/marionette.controller.md) as follows:

```js
// controllers/custom_controller.js

this.customView.bind("some:custom:event", this.customEventHandler, this);
```

The custom event is triggered within the view:

```js
// views/custom_view.js

onSomething: function() {
  this.trigger("some:custom:event");
}
```

I would like to check whether `this.customView` has a event handler for `some:custom:event`.

Comment: Just to clarify what is a sample som:event you are looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.customView._events` is an object of the bound events. So to check if the event exists:

```js
if (this.customView._events["some:custom:event"]) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Great! Do you know if I can also check which event handler is bound? Please feel free to extend your answer.

Comment: you can see if it is a particular event handler by using this.customView._events["some:custom:event"] === this.customEventHandler

Comment: Looks reasonable however the expression returns `false` when I check it within `custom_controller/customEventHandler`.